# Websphere + Spring DMLC + MQ -J2CA0045E: Connection not available while invoking method createOrWaitForConnection for resource JMS

Tags: ibm-mq, spring-jms, websphere-8

We are using Spring in our Web application.

I want to concurrently listen the messages from `MQ` using using Spring's `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`(DMLC).

In websphere I didnt change any connection configurations.

**Issue:**

When DMLC listner tried to receive few(6 messages) messages concurrently from Queue, Websphere Application Server logged FFDC incident logs.

Can anyone help me If I missing the connection configurations?

**Version:**

Server: Websphere Application Server 8.5

**MessageListener:**

```
<bean id="jmsContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="destinationName" ref="queue"/>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="myMessageListener"/>
    <property name ="concurrentConsumers" value ="5"/>
    <property name ="maxConcurrentConsumers" value ="20"/>
    <property name="idleTaskExecutionLimit" value="10" />
    <property name="idleConsumerLimit" value="5" />
    <property name="recoveryInterval" value="60000" />        
</bean>
```

**QueueConnectionfactory - Connection pools:**
[image: Image of default Connection pool of QueueConnection factory]

**Logs in Server logs:**

```
[8/1/17 12:47:54:071 ]  FreePool      E    J2CA0045E: Connection not available while invoking method createOrWaitForConnection for resource JMS$ConnectionFactory$JMSManagedConnection@0.
[8/1/17 12:43:44:131 ]  FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on WebSphere/path/path/logFileName.txt Max connections reached 869
[8/1/17 12:43:44:131 ]  FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on WebSphere/path/path/logFileName.txt com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSConnectionHandle.createSession 1051
[8/1/17 12:44:44:132 ]  SystemOut     O 12:44:44.132 [jmsContainer-11] WARN  o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer - Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'queue:' - trying to recover. Cause: Failed to create session; nested exception is com.ibm.websphere.ce.j2c.ConnectionWaitTimeoutException: CWTE_NORMAL_J2CA1009
[8/1/17 12:44:45:153 ]  FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on WebSphere/path/path/logFileName.txt com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSMessageConsumerHandle.receive 264
[8/1/17 12:44:55:304 ]  SystemOut     O 12:44:55.304 [jmsContainer-11] INFO  o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer - Successfully refreshed JMS Connection
[8/1/17 12:47:55:310 ]  FreePool      E   J2CA0045E: Connection not available while invoking method createOrWaitForConnection for resource JMS$ConnectionFactory$JMSManagedConnection@0
```

**FFDC log incident:**

```
[8/1/17 13:41:03:046]     FFDC Exception:com.ibm.websphere.ce.j2c.ConnectionWaitTimeoutException SourceId:Max connections reached ProbeId:869 Reporter:com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager@aad4897
com.ibm.websphere.ce.j2c.ConnectionWaitTimeoutException: CWTE_NORMAL_J2CA1009
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createOrWaitForConnection(FreePool.java:1782)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:3816)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:3092)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateMCWrapper(ConnectionManager.java:1548)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateConnection(ConnectionManager.java:1031)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSConnectionHandle.createSession(JMSConnectionHandle.java:1434)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createSession(JmsAccessor.java:196)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.access$12(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.initResourcesIfNecessary(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1091)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1070)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1063)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:960)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:863)

==> Performing default dump from com.ibm.ejs.j2c.DiagnosticModuleForJ2C :Tue Aug 01 13:41:03 2017
Maximum number of connections has been reached, and the connection request has been waiting longer than:ConnectionWaitTime.  Two possible solutions  : increase the max number of connections, or increase the:ConnectionWaitTime.:
   Maximum Connections           = :10
   Current number of connections = :10
   Connection Wait Timout        = :180
If the current number of connections is not greater than or equal to max connections, :there has been a WebSphere internal error.:
This =  BEGIN:com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager@aad4897
com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager::tc BEGIN:com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent@330b9221
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivLevel:10
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivName:com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivDebugEnabled:false
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivEventEnabled:false
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivEntryEnabled:false
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivDetailEnabled:false
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivConfigEnabled:false
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivInfoEnabled:true
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivServiceEnabled:true
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivWarningEnabled:true
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivErrorEnabled:true
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivFatalEnabled:true
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent::defaultMessageFile:com.ibm.ejs.resources.seriousMessages
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent::EXTENSION_NAME_DPID:DiagnosticProvider
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent::ivDumpEnabled:false
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent::ivResourceBundleName:com.ibm.ws.j2c.resources.J2CAMessages
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent::ivLogger:com.ibm.ws.logging.WsLogger@8273a12c
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent::ivDiagnosticProviderID:null
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent::anyTracingEnabled:null
 END:com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent@330b9221

[8/1/17 13:42:03:108 ]     FFDC Exception:com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedIllegalStateException SourceId:com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSMessageConsumerHandle.receive ProbeId:264 Reporter:com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSMessageConsumerHandle@ab2dfd8d
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedIllegalStateException: JMSCC0032: This message consumer is closed.
An application called a method that must not be used after the message consumer is closed.
Ensure that the message consumer is not closed before calling the method.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:58)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:542)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:314)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.nls.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:228)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsErrorUtils.createException(JmsErrorUtils.java:104)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.State.checkNotClosed(State.java:145)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageConsumerImpl.receive(JmsMessageConsumerImpl.java:413)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQMessageConsumer.receive(MQMessageConsumer.java:212)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSMessageConsumerHandle.receive(JMSMessageConsumerHandle.java:553)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSMessageConsumerHandle.receive(JMSMessageConsumerHandle.java:501)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveMessage(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:431)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:311)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:264)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1071)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1063)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:960)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:863)

==> Performing default dump from com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSDiagnosticModule :Tue Aug 01 13:42:03 2017
+Data for directive [defaultdefault] obtained.:
==> Dump complete for com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSDiagnosticModule :Tue Aug 01 13:42:03 CEST 201

[8/1/17 13:50:13:445]     FFDC Exception:javax.jms.IllegalStateException SourceId:com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSConnectionHandle.createSession ProbeId:1044 Reporter:com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSConnectionHandle@e8e11802
javax.jms.IllegalStateException: Connection closed
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSConnectionHandle.checkOpen(JMSConnectionHandle.java:837)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSConnectionHandle.createSession(JMSConnectionHandle.java:1430)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createSession(JmsAccessor.java:196)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.access$12(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.initResourcesIfNecessary(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1091)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1070)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1063)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:960)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:863)

8/2/17 15:30:31:874 CEST]     FFDC Exception:javax.jms.IllegalStateException SourceId:com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSConnectionHandle.stop ProbeId:477 Reporter:com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSConnectionHandle@5c5db824
javax.jms.IllegalStateException: Method stop not permitted
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSCMUtils.methodNotPermittedException(JMSCMUtils.java:244)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSConnectionHandle.checkRestrictedMethod(JMSConnectionHandle.java:854)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSConnectionHandle.stop(JMSConnectionHandle.java:768)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.stopSharedConnection(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:460)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.stopSharedConnection(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:791)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.doStop(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:326)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.stop(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:302)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.stop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:582)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStop(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:223)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$2(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:207)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.stop(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.stopBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:196)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onClose(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:113)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1045)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1000)
    at com.bnppf.ssc.imb.sf.fwk.mia.context.CloseableGenericWebApplicationContext.close(CloseableGenericWebApplicationContext.java:34)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:548)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:142)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextDestroyed(WebApp.java:1765)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.destroy(WebApp.java:3131)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.destroy(WebAppImpl.java:1551)
    at com.ibm.ws.container.AbstractContainer.destroy(AbstractContainer.java:75)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.destroy(WebGroup.java:228)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.removeWebApplication(WebGroup.java:269)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHost.removeWebApplication(VirtualHost.java:296)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.removeWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:211)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.removeWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:820)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.uninstall(WebContainerImpl.java:458)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.stop(WebContainerImpl.java:729)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.stop(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1218)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStop(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1375)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.stop(DeployedModuleImpl.java:671)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.stop(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1149)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.stopApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:952)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.stopApplicationImpl(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1488)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.stop(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2249)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.stop(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:492)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.stop(CompositionUnitImpl.java:141)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$2.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:795)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5387)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5603)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.stopCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:830)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.stopCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:736)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.stopApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1465)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor133.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:292)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1261)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:311)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:88)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1255)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:1093)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:832)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:814)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.CallRouter.route(CallRouter.java:247)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink.doWork(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:360)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink$IPCConnectorReadCallback.complete(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:602)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1881)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your current Spring configuration is draining the whole connection pool. So either configuration is not correct or you are leaking connections somewhere.

```
==> Performing default dump from com.ibm.ejs.j2c.DiagnosticModuleForJ2C :Tue Aug 01 13:41:03 2017
Maximum number of connections has been reached, and the connection request has been waiting longer than:ConnectionWaitTime.  Two possible solutions  : increase the max number of connections, or increase the:ConnectionWaitTime.:
   Maximum Connections           = :10
   Current number of connections = :10
   Connection Wait Timout        = :180
```

so either fix the configuration - maybe start with the simpler one and remove:

```
<property name ="maxConcurrentConsumers" value ="20"/>
<property name="idleTaskExecutionLimit" value="10" />
<property name="idleConsumerLimit" value="5" />
```

or just use normal Java EE MDB for reciving messages instead of this Spring.

Comment: I am using Spring as the DMLC of Spring supports concurrent consumers and it takes care of multithreading. I want to treat the messages concurrently. So I didnt choose Java EE MDB. So as you said I shall fix the configuration.

Comment: I also need the property maxConcurrentConsumers. Should I try by increasing the maximumConnections in the Connection pool of QueueConnectionFactory in WAS?

Comment: Each Java EE server will allow concurrent consumers on MDB and will be handling threading for that, so that's not a point. And yes you can try to increase pool size in QCF it will definitely help.

Comment: Ok sure I will try by increasing the maximum connections in coonection pool. As mentioned in [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_i5_54/rzatz/51/admin/help/udat_conpoolset.html) default maximum connections is 10 and the Lower settings, such as 10-30 connections, perform better than higher settings, such as 100.